# Select value of key2 where value of key1 equals?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json object. When the user selects a color from a `select` box, I would like to load the corresponding `qty`. How would you go about selecting qty where color equals `$('#colorselector').val()` ?

```
{
    "products": [{
        color: "yellow",
        qty: 22
    }, {
        color: "red",
        qty: 45
    }, {
        color: "blue",
        qty: 3
    }]
}
```

Comment: Is the question regarding json structure? if yes and you only have color and quantity, you can use color as key and qty as value: `{ "yellow" : 22, "red" : 45 }`

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonObj.products.forEach(function(el) {
    if(el.color == $('#colorselector').val()) {
        console.log("Qty: " + el.qty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, like you can do something like the following:

```
{
    "products": {
      "yellow":22,
      "red":45,
      "blue": 3
    }
}
```

and accessing it by

```
qty = obj.products[$('#colorselector').val()]
```

but as i said it depends on how you are going to use it

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    "products": [{
        color: "yellow",
        qty: 22
    }, {
        color: "red",
        qty: 45
    }, {
        color: "blue",
        qty: 3
    }]
};

console.log(data.products[0].qty);
```